# Accessing velocity context in MethodExceptionEventHandler

Tags: velocity

How to access velocity context object in methodexception method in MethodExceptionEventHandler class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to make your handler implement the `org.apache.velocity.util.ContextAware` interface and implement its single method:

```
public void setContext( Context context );
```

which will be called prior to each invocation of the handler.